# How does my country block this NSFW website when I use DoH and the site uses cloudflare?

Tags: networking, security, dns, routing

I use Cloudflare DNS over HTTPS in my browser (Edge/Firefox), and the same encrypted DNS in OS, Windows 11 and found that the website I chose, xhamster.com, is behind Cloudflare as well, according to https://www.whois.com/whois/xhamster.com

so I want to know, how is it possible that the website gets blocked? other websites behind Cloudflare work fine, DoH is successful as Cloudflare's secure DNS checker website shows. my router uses ISP's DNS but that shouldn't matter, right?

[image]

I used Pingplotter and found out there are a bunch of private IP addresses between my router and the first router outside of my country, so something is happening here.

can someone help me find out how they are blocking my access to that website?

I also force all connections to use HTTPS only. is the lack of ESNI/ECH the reason they can block that website? or do they use the old IP based method even for websites behind Cloudflare whose server IP is hidden.

all the websites that get blocked by my country produce "ERR_TIMED_OUT" in the browser.

p.s I can use VPN or Cloudflare WARP to circumvent this restriction, but my sole purpose for this post is to find out "how" they can do this with all this security measures in place.

Comment: Very likely SNI is the culprit. When your browser is setting up TLS with the Cloudflare IP, it openly tells which domain it wants to connect to.

Comment: @gronostaj Thank you, tried Firefox 103 with ECH and Firefox 80 with ESNI, then visited https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/encrypted-sni/ with both, still said not using ESNI/ECH .

Comment: Are you by chance using Cloudflare DNS and/or a third-party DNS server as your configured DNS NameServer for your router?  Cloudflare (among others) have versions of their DNS service that filter the type of content on that website.  Does not matter if you are using HTTPS when the domain is known and is easily placed in a category.

Comment: @Ramhound good point, but no I use Cloudflare DoH on OS and browser, my router uses ISP's plaintext DNS, router doesn't support any secure DNS. but doesn't only the last DNS used matter? in this case, the one in the browser?